# MySQL to php temp result

Tags: php, mysql, temperature

I've created a MySQL database which logs the date and time in one column and the current temp in another column, the temperature is checked every 10 mins via cron-e, all this works great but I'm really struggling to write or find some php to retrieve the last temp recorded, I have found a php that get all the data and tried to alter the query but just end up with [] displayed on page and no temps.

I'm sorry if this is a basic question, but I'm really struggling with this code learning.

Comment: Hello, could you please add more information like : the shape of your table, the query you executed, the result you got and the result you expected. And welcome to StackOverflow !

Comment: What is your query?

Comment: So are you expecting us to write the code for you? Then it is off topic for Stack Overflow. Please learn [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: `select * from \`table\` order by \`field\` desc limit 1`

Comment: Thanks for the replys, As soon as I finish work I will add the code I have, I understand this is prob a flustrating question to answer but I really can't get my head round it as I only started learning two weeks ago

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sort the table by date and time and the latest temp will be the final row - post an sql dump of a sample table and maybe I can help more

Comment: Why do we just vote people down and vote off topic when we could just read the question, understand the needs and try and help SO is an awesome site but we need to be patient - the question had a specific problem and desired behaviour, 'shortest possible code' there was no code - can not get shorter than that - so it does  include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary  -no code needed and we did not need to write his code - just help him !!!! Guys - stop sticking to red tape and try and help people - surely that is why this site exists!